# Why does my React app only load on refresh without cache?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Seems this would be more straightforward, but I am stumped. My React app is being served with Webpack and if I open up the localhost in an Incognito browser (or refresh a regular tab without cache) the content appears. But otherwise I get these errors in my inspector:

[image]

[image]

`src/index.js` and `public/index.html` files are like a basic Create React App config, like so:

src/index.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./components/App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

public/index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Index</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the Webpack is as follows:

```js
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack')
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

const config = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx', '.css']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(tsx?|jsx?)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              rootMode: 'upward'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'source-map-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
        use: ['file-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  node: {
    fs: 'empty'
  },
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv({
      path: './.env',
      systemvars: true
    }),
    new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({ eslint: true })
  ]
}

module.exports = env => {
  const styleRule = {
    test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
  }

  const htmlPluginConfig = { template: 'public/index.html', inject: true }
  config.module.rules.push(styleRule)
  config.plugins.push(new HtmlWebpackPlugin(htmlPluginConfig))
  config.devtool = 'inline-source-map'
  config.devServer = {
    contentBase: './src',
    overlay: true,
    port: 8080
  }
  return config
}
```

I know something is jacked, but can't put my finger on it.

Comment: In what you have shown you are missing your script tag to load the bundle.js. add <script src="bundle.js"></script> in your  public/index.html right before the end body tag.

Comment: Thanks, I included that change. Unfortunately it has no effect on the loading issue, I still need to refresh without cache to see content.

Comment: have you cleared your cache?

Comment: also remove any script tag that is referencing main.js